# Objective-c how to Synchronize iphone apps for develop other source or website data

Tags: objective-c, xcode, edit

how to Synchronize  iphone apps for develop other source or website data

anyone can ask me thanks

please send me some link,or tutorial or demo ,example,script  (http://status.net/wiki/Building_StatusNet_Mobile_from_source)

i am use mac os to edit xcode

i'm use open source to handle iphone of that part

jackie chan

Answer (score 0):

You need to redo your question. What are you trying to do?

It sounds like you are trying to sync code between computers. In which case google SVN and GIT.

Comment: my friend is by boss order , 1st the order say to staff

Comment: by the 1 st order staff is change any Variable on his part,so my friend have no idea to change his  part ,because  the staff alway change by boss order or they no Coordination so  Failure